# Mockito - configure a mock so it will call a method with an injected parameter

Tags: java, tdd, mockito, spy

I have a method in a class, `ConsoleHandler`, an instance of which I'm spying on:

```
setIndexManager( IndexManager im );
```

I want to say "when you call this method, call it not with the parameter you want to call it with, but instead with such-and-such a parameter" (namely a mock object).

I tried doing this:

```
    doAnswer( new Answer<Void>(){
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            ((ConsoleHandler)invocation.getMock()).setIndexManager( newMockIM );
            return null;
        }}).when( spyCH ).setIndexManager( any( IndexManager.class ));
```

... unfortunately this caused an infinite loop...

Then I thought: OK, if you can specify in the `when` clause that any `IndexManager parameter` should trigger this, **except** for `mockIM`, maybe you can stop that infinite recursion:

```
    doAnswer( new Answer<Void>(){
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            ((ConsoleHandler)invocation.getMock()).setIndexManager( newMockIM );
            return null;
        }}).when( spyCH ).setIndexManager( not( newMockIM ));
```

... but `not` doesn't work like that...

Is there any way of doing this? I did quite a close examination of possible similar questions which came up but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Change your stubbing so that it only kicks in if the provided argument is not  your mock.

So the last line would be

```
}}).when(spyCH).setIndexManager(AdditionalMatchers.not( ArgumentMatchers.eq(newMockIM)) );
```

Then the call within your `Answer` won't re-trigger the stubbed call.

**Note**

I answered before you added the second half of your question, but I believe this is OK.  The argument to `not` has to be a matcher, but you've provided a value.  So all you were missing is the `eq`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks... as you can see this thought occurred (as so often) just after posting. But I guarantee it would have taken me at least an hour to work out how to do it!

Comment: Only one slight problem: I'm getting a "type Matchers is deprecated" warning.  This is Mockito 2.4.1: we're apparently supposed to use `ArgumentMatchers` instead...

Comment: OK, fair enough.  I haven't really kept up with everything in the newer versions of Mockito.  I don't understand why the team are modifying and deprecating as many things as they are, and I don't understand the motivation for some of the breaking changes they've put in the later versions.  I hope the method names are the same in the new `ArgumentMatchers`.

Comment: Yes, your solution works like a treat. I know nothing about Mockito deprecation policy/politics!

Comment: @mikerodent Can you please edit my answer with something non-deprecated?  Thanks.